# boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<something>> usage of operator[]

Tags: c++11, boost

I have a struct that looks like this.

```
typedef struct superCellBoxStruct {
    float_tt cmx,cmy,cmz;  /* fractional center of mass coordinates */
    float_tt ax,by,cz;
    boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<atom>> atoms; /* contains all the atoms within the super cell */
} superCellBox;
```

now when I want to access `atoms[i]` I get

> error: invalid use of ‘boost::detail::sp_array_access >::type {aka void}’

What is the proper way of passing around a shared vector in my application, or what is the correct way to access its operator[]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefer `unique_ptr<T[]>` if you can, because you get `operator[]` for free (§ 20.7.1.3.3):

[image]

Quick demo:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec08b974e5006b5d)</kbd>**

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> p(new int[3] { 1,2,3 });

    std::cout << "Before: " << p[0] << ", " << p[1] << ", " << p[2] << ";\n";
    p[1] = 42;
    std::cout << "After:  " << p[0] << ", " << p[1] << ", " << p[2] << ";\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
Before: 1, 2, 3;
After:  1, 42, 3;
```

## UPDATE

In response to the comment, just make a small wrapper:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/58007b98bdacfe47)</kbd>**

```
#include <memory>

template <typename RAContainer> struct shared_randomaccess_container
{
    template <typename... A> shared_randomaccess_container(A&&... args) 
        : _ptr(new RAContainer{ std::forward<A>(args)... })
    { }
    template <typename T> shared_randomaccess_container(std::initializer_list<T> init)
        : _ptr(std::make_shared<RAContainer>(init))
    { }

    auto begin() const -> typename RAContainer::const_iterator { return _ptr->begin(); }
    auto end  () const -> typename RAContainer::const_iterator { return _ptr->end  (); }
    auto begin()       -> typename RAContainer::iterator       { return _ptr->begin(); }
    auto end  ()       -> typename RAContainer::iterator       { return _ptr->end  (); }

    template <typename Idx>
    typename RAContainer::value_type const& operator[](Idx i) const { return (*_ptr)[i]; }
    template <typename Idx>
    typename RAContainer::value_type& operator[](Idx i) { return (*_ptr)[i]; }

    template <typename Idx>
    typename RAContainer::value_type const& at(Idx i) const { return _ptr->at(i); }
    template <typename Idx>
    typename RAContainer::value_type& at(Idx i) { return _ptr->at(i); }

  protected:
    using Ptr = std::shared_ptr<RAContainer>;
    Ptr _ptr;
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// demo intances
#include <vector>

template <typename... Ts> using shared_vector = shared_randomaccess_container<std::vector<Ts...> >;
```

You can use it like:

```
shared_vector<int> sv {1,2,3};

std::cout << "Before: ";
for (auto i : sv) std::cout << i << " ";

sv[1] = 42;
std::cout << "\nAfter:  ";
for (auto i : sv) std::cout << i << " ";
```

Prints:

```
Before: 1 2 3 
After:  1 42 3
```

---

### Bonus

Let's also support aggregate initializing containers with the same technique

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e035859266a13a1f)</kbd>**

Output:

```
void test() [with With = std::vector<int>]
Before: 1 2 3 
After:  1 42 3 

void test() [with With = std::array<int, 3ul>]
Before: 1 2 3 
After:  1 42 3 

void test() [with With = shared_randomaccess_container<std::vector<int>, false>]
Before: 1 2 3 
After:  1 42 3 

void test() [with With = shared_randomaccess_container<std::array<int, 3ul>, true>]
Before: 1 2 3 
After:  1 42 3
```

Comment: But what if I want the memory management features of std::vector, i.e not reallocate my array by hand?

Comment: Cool stuff man, pretty advanced but does what I want! You stole the answer :)

Comment: Now, would you say using that kind of construct is bad practice?

Comment: I'd say it depends on the use case really. I agree with @sbabbi that it looks like you could be putting the whole `superCellBox` in a shared_ptr (which is why I upvoted that answer)

Answer (score 3):

Pick one:

```
(*atoms)[i]    
atoms->operator[](i);
```

I usually go with the first, but they are all equivalent.

As a side note, in my experience a `shared_ptr<vector>` like that is usually a symptom of a bad design, maybe you want to put the entire `superCellBox` in a `shared_ptr`?

Also, this is not C, use `struct name {};` instead `typedef struct tagName {} name;`

Comment: Thanks, I also thought about 'shared_ptr<superCellBox>'